# Django: built-in template tag ... not able to evaluate strings correctly

Tags: python, django, django-templates, built-in

In my html file I code

```
print({{ incident.status }})
{% if incident.status == "open" %}
    <h1>Incident {{ incident.pk }} - Open</h1><br>
{% else %}
    <h1>Incident {{ incident.pk }} - Closed</h1><br>
{% endif %}
```

[image: built-in template tag not working as I think it should.]

I can't for the life of me get what I believe is `open` to equal `open`. Am I not using the built-in correctly?

```
class Status(models.Model):
        status = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=100)
class Incident(models.Model):
        status = models.ForeignKey(Status, default="open")
```

Status choices are open and closed.

Comment: Wat kind of thing is `status`? Is it a CharField?

Comment: Yes. I updated the post with information from my models.py

Comment: From your snippet, `status` is not a CharField but a ForeignKey. Maybe you meant to compare `incident.status.status` instead of `incident.status`? (The default for Incident.status is also off.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`incident.status` is **not** a string! Is reference to object "incident". Even if it's string representation is "open", it won't give true when compared to string "open".

Use `incident.status.status` in comparison.